# how to load json data available in txt file using put table in oracle NoSql database

Tags: json, database, bigdata, oracle-nosql

I have two txt files containing Json data available in Linux system.
I have created respective tables in Oracle NoSql for these two files.
Now, I want to load this data in to created table in Oracle NoSql Database.

```
Syntax:
put table -name <name> [if-absent | -if-present ]
[-json <string>] [-file <file>] [-exact] [-update] 

Explanation:
Put a row into the named table. The table name is a dot-separated name with the format table[.childTableName]*.

where:

-if-absent

Indicates to put a row only if the row does not exist.

-if-present

Indicates to put a row only if the row already exists.

-json

Indicates that the value is a JSON string.

-file

Can be used to load JSON strings from a file.

-exact

Indicates that the input JSON string or file must contain values for all columns in the table and cannot contain extraneous fields.

-update

Can be used to partially update the existing record.
```

Now, I am using below command to load:

```
kv-> put table -name tablename -file /path-to-folder/file.txt
Error handling command put table -name tablename -file /path-to-folder/file.txt: Illegal value for numeric field predicted_probability: 0.0. Expected FLOAT, is DOUBLE
kv->
```

I am not able to find the reason. Learned members, Please help.

Thank You for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I solved it. Actually there was a conflict between table data type and json string data type. Later I realized this.

Thanks